# Using JS modules in HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, module, es6-class

Since I’m converting  my  Javascript code to **node.js**, I’m changing my old code to adapt it to **ES6**, using "**Class**" and "**module**" instead of just using "**function**" components.

I first renewed the server side, and all went well. But now, I’m trying to get to the client side, and I have a problem converting  the old coding fashion to the new one.

In the following example, you can find 2 applets:

The « Module » applet is made of 2 files : « **FooClass.js** » and  « **Foo_mod.html** ».

The « Component » one  includes  « **FooComp.js** » and « **Foo_comp.html**» .

**All 4 files are stored in the same folder**.
Both applets are supposed to display an alert message saying  « ***x = 7*** », but the « *module* » applet  doesn’t, meanwhile  the old fashioned one does it correctly. **Still, there is no problem to reach the js  file from the html code when pressing Ctrl+click on the js file name in VS Code**. So there must be some error in my new code, but I can’t find it. Thanks by advance if anyone can help me...

### 1 - The module-oriented applet (doesn't work):

**FooClass.js :**

```
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        this.foo = "";
    }
    cinq (x) {  //(real)->real
        return x + 5;
     }
}
module.exports = Foo;
```

---

**Foo_mod.html :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="module" src="./FooClass.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var fx = new Foo();
        var x = fx.cinq(2);
        alert("x = " + x);  // must display "x=7"
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**2 - The old way applet : (works fine)**

**FooComp.js**

```
    function cinq (x)  { //(real)->real
        return x + 5;
     }
// end of file FooComp.js
```

---

**Foo_Comp.html :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>FooComp</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./FooComp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var y = 2;
        var x = cinq(y);
        alert("x = " + x);  // must display "x=7"
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your `FooClass.js` file to use the `ES6 export` *syntax* instead of `module.exports`:

```js
export class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.foo = "";
  }
  cinq(x) {
    return x + 5;
  }
}
```

You can `import` the `Foo` class using the `import` *statement*:

```html
<script type="module">
    import { Foo } from "./FooClass.js";
    var fx = new Foo();
    var x = fx.cinq(2);
    alert("x = " + x); // should display "x=7"
</script>
```